# Delphi 2007 TPopupMenu hides selected item image on Windows 8

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

on Windows 8 the TPopupMenu component doesn't show the selected item image:

[image: Not selected item, with regular image]

[image: Selected item: no more image]

Is there a fix for this? Or a workaround?

With DelphiXE3 this is fixed, but I need this app to be compiled with D2007.

I've installed IDE Fix Pack 2007 4.3 and VCL Fix Pack 1.4 too, on Delphi 2007 December 2007 Update.

Comment: You mean a workaround other than upgrading to a version of Delphi that is not nearly a decade old, that is aware of current OS versions and how to work with them?

Comment: I know ... But this app is D2007 compiled with legacy libraries. And XE7 is no bug free.

Comment: Update: this issue is gone. Menu icons are ok on Windows 10 PC and on Windows 2012 and Windows 2016 terminal server. But it is still visible in some older terminal server.